# Can I specify where a viewModel is to be found?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to put my partial view model in a folder inside an area. Is there a way that I can specify the location of _City or does it only look in the default location?

```
    public ActionResult CheckCity(string id)
    {
        var model = xxx
        return PartialView("_City", model);
    }
```

Comment: I think you meant View not a ViewModel - would be good to fix the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a relative path:-

return PartialView("~/Views/SomeFolder/AnotherFolder/SomeView.cshtml", model);